# what bios interrupt exist for networking

Tags: networking, interrupt, bios

is there any bios interrupt that send and receive packet over the net?

if I want to make a boot loader which communicate with other computer, what am I supposed to learn?

any keywords? documents?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard PC BIOS has no runtime APIs for network communication.

Pretty much the only networking code you find in a BIOS is the PXE boot loader, which provides a pre-boot environment for downloading a kernel from a network server and executing it.  This does not provide any post-boot runtime services though.

If you want to do network communication while you are running from disk, you need to implement your own networking stack.